# Email to Custom-Obj functionality

Tags: apex, email, custom-object, case, email2case

I want to know if it is possible to create an email-to-customObj functionality in Salesforce? My organization is heavily using the Case object and do not want to add more to it. I want to create a record on custom object when an email is received in Salesforce org.

Comment: Hi Shwarma, Welcome to SFSE! yes you can create records when an email is received. Ty using Apex Email Services, which would process the contents of the email and create/update a record based on that. Ref: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_inbound_what_is.htm

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, currently its not possible as per standard email to case functionality but you can implement this by using email services in salesforce.

Refer the [Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdlmEUAR/email-to-custom-object-same-functionality-as-email-to-case) from idea exchange and upvote same functionality for custom object.

Refer the [Apex email services](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_inbound_what_is.htm) for custom implementation.